# How to select parent element by which include an img child with specific src attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a list of images like so:

```
<div>
    <div class="imgCnr">
    <img src="abc.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="imgCnr">
    <img src="def.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="imgCnr">
    <img src="ghi.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="imgCnr">
    <img src="jkl.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

How to select and remove parent element by which include an img child with specific src attribute

My guess:

```
var imgElmnt = document.querySelectorAll("imgCnr > img[src='def.jpg']");
imgElmnt.parent().remove();
```

Desired result:

```
<div>
    <div class="imgCnr">
    <img src="abc.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="imgCnr">
    <img src="ghi.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="imgCnr">
    <img src="jkl.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$(imgElmnt).parent().remove();` will do it for Jquery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("img[src='def.jpg']").parent().remove()
```

You were applying jQuery methods on HTML DOM Elements, instead they are applicable only on jQuery objects.

And in case you want to achieve this using plain javascript then do

```js
var imgElmnt = document.querySelectorAll("img[src='def.jpg']");
imgElmnt[0].parentNode.remove();
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="imgCnr">
    <img src="abc.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="imgCnr">
    <img src="def.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="imgCnr">
    <img src="ghi.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="imgCnr">
    <img src="jkl.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I hate how people just shove jQuery into things. This is easily accomplished without jQuery, the line count and complexity doesn't change, and it doesn't require you to load around 30kb of library

Comment: @zevee Oh dont hate anything :) Its not good! Let people use what they want to use :)

Comment: Okay, let me just get my nail, and another nail to nail it in with

Comment: @zevee I agree jQuery is a 30kb library but essentially most of the time people intend to establish the tradeoff between 30 kb and making things easier. Its okay.. try and understand their emotions.. :)

Comment: The difference between your code and mine is literally 18 characters. At one point, it stops being `making things easier`, and starts being `adding on bloat`

Comment: @zevee I agree... But its okay.. I have provided both the solutions :)

Answer (score 1):

You were close:

```
var imgElmnt = document.querySelector("img[src='def.jpg']");
imgElmnt.parentNode.remove();
```

Comment: If you are using `querySelectorAll(` then you will need to get the 0th element. `imgElmnt[0]`.

Comment: Right. Forgot about that.

Answer (score 1):

You can select the image by source by `[src='source']`

```js
$(function() {
 let toRemove = "def.jpg";
 $("div img[src='" + toRemove + "']").parent().remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="imgCnr">
    <img src="abc.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="imgCnr">
    <img src="def.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="imgCnr">
    <img src="ghi.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="imgCnr">
    <img src="jkl.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I hate how people just shove jQuery into things. This is easily accomplished without jQuery, the line count and complexity doesn't change, and it doesn't require you to load around 30kb of library

Comment: This what makes SO a great community for devs. People can suggest their preferred code. If you hate it, too bad. Just dont **shove** your hatred to other people too.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but I also act in the best interest of the people who are asking the question, and it's just ridiculous to load a library so big just to make your code 18 characters smaller in length

Comment: How can you tell the *best interest* of the OP, Do you know his/her entire code? Here is SO, only snippets are being posted. If the user is using wordress for example, jQuery is already loaded. Then why use vanilla when you can use jQuery.

Comment: you don't even know if he/she is already using jquery library @zevee. The libraries exist to use them

Comment: Okay, I agree that I do not know what they had loaded before. However, it's still faster not to use jquery, even if it's only marginal performance gains.

Comment: Sure, everybody knows that. That idea is not ground breaking news. But still, people are using it because it also gives alot of advantages. I am not here to defend jQuery. As you probably know, we want to be on topic. If you want to discuss the speed of jQuery. Go find the right post. Just saying.

Comment: @zevee "However, it's still faster not to use jquery, even if it's only marginal performance gains." You have a point there.